# Creating NSManagedObject classes in xcode8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, xcode8

How to create NsmanagedObject classes in xcode8, it is causing "no such file or directory" while making archieve, which is the best way to create and to use by using xcode 8, please need exact way step by step.

Comment: Why you people giving downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried googling this? If you did, you would've found tutorials like the one listed below.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/145809/getting-started-core-data-tutorial